# Vs2012 TFS Pending Changes is not showing nuget packages

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, nuget

I have added several nuget packages to my project.

When I look at the solution/packages directory in TFS file explorer I see all the "adds" of the packages.

When I look in pending changes, the packages are not listed. I am set to "All Changes" not "Solution Changes"

The issue is that I would like to shelve these changes in order to do a build (Latest Changes + shelveset) to test prior to checking in, but the shelve command will only let me shelve things that appear in the pending changes window.

My fallback is going to be to do a checkin and then rollback if it fails, but this will cause disruption to the other users and a bunch of paperwork, so i would like to avoid that.

Comment: Check your exclusions tab and the level (tree depth) that you are performing the add operation at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the pending changes window always filters the display of certain files, but if you click on "Show all Included changes" they do show up.  even though the files are not visible in the pending list, they do check in or shelve correctly.